# linux and snapshot show different memory usage in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

The server often crashes with an "out of memory" error. If you check the tools, you will see that NodeJS is consuming a lot of memory. However, the inspect tool shows normal memory usage.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone explain why this is so? How to find the real reason for the server crash?

The server is AWS ec2 (t3a.micro)

Comment: `htop` does not report the exact memory usage most of the time. I'd suggest using `pm2` for monitoring your app. https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

Comment: @undefined thank you. I installed pm2 but still don't understand how it works. The heap size is 46 MB and the memory used is 183 MB. What was the other 137 MB of memory spent on?

Comment: Ok, I think I found it https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1518

Comment: Think you need to share part of code to make your question clear.